# Magento - Add custom table data into Products collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection, resource-model

I have created a custom table which stores the `listId` (you can think of it sort of wish list) and product id and created Model and Model resources. What I need is the actual product data based on the product id's who are stored in custom table `company_mymodule_shortlist_product` . Plus I need to apply the custom filter/sorting on the collection. E.g. I want to filter the product collection base on the `create_at` filed which is available in my custom table.

Below is the code of Model, Model resource and part of `config.xml`

**config.xml**

```
<models>
    <mymodule>
        <class>Company_MyModule_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>mymodule_resource</resourceModel>
    </mymodule>
    <mymodule_resource>
        <class>Company_MyModule_ModelResource</class>
        <entities>
            <shortlist>
                <table>It stores the list name and its id</table>
            </shortlist>
            <shortlist_product>
                <table>company_mymodule_shortlist_product</table>
            </shortlist_product>
        </entities>
    </mymodule_resource>
</models>
```

**Model:**

```
class Company_MyModule_Model_Shortlist_Product extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
public function getAllProductsRelatedToShortListId()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('mymodule/shortlist_product_collection');
        foreach($collection as $collections) {
            $collections;
        }
    }
}
```

**Resource Model:**

```
class Company_MyModule_Model_Resource_Shortlist_Product_Collection extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
{

}
```

---

### Edit:

After hours of digging I found that I will need to extend the Resource collection of `shortlist_product` with `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` which I have done successfully.
But now I do not know how to add the custom table data into the product collection so that I get all the required products data. Infact a proper Magento product collection with all sorting, filtering etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to join your custom table with product collection based on product_id.
Refer this link
http://magentotutorial.in/join-custom-table-to-product-collection-in-magento/